# Is the operator<< defined by sf::Packet working with (*this) of a sf::Packet derived class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sfml

I got a class that is derived from sf::Packet which gets passed an Integer referring to iots type in its constructor. Now in the constructor I try to add the Integer to the data of the sf::Packet like so:

```
class Packet : public sf::Packet
{
public:
    Packet(sf::Int32 type)
    {
        m_Type = type;
        (*this) << m_Type;
    }

    sf::Int32 m_Type
}
```

However if I try to extract that Integer on the server side with the operator>>, the Integer remains what it was initialized to.

**Now my Question:** Is it even possible to use this operator with the *this* pointer in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my Question: Is it even possible to use this operator with the this pointer in this case?

Yes, its OK. Take a look at following example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8f8d5b45ade0ad8.

you should be able to verify this with debugger on your own.

> However if I try to extract that Integer on the server side with the operator>>

its possible that the error occurs somewhere else

Comment: Ok thank you :) I will have a look at the Rest of the code then